# Low resolution mode only after resume followed by login loop in Ubuntu GNOME 16.04.3

Tags: login, display-manager

This is my first Linux encounter. I have Asus ROG gl752vw, i7 6700, 16GB RAM 128 GB SSD, 1 TB HDD nvidia geforce 960m 4GB machine preinstalled with Windows 10.

I installed Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 with live USB made with win32 disk imager (before that made backup using Macrium reflect, following instructions from [a blog in everydaylinuxuser](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2016/05/how-to-dual-boot-ubuntu-and-windows-10.html)) as per blog, I didn't choose the "install alongside Windows" option, but manually created partitions. Secure boot was turned off and fast startup also off.

After installation I have to change boot order in BIOS for Ubuntu, or Windows Boot Manager starts by default. Ubuntu desktop never booted on its own. When I resumed from recovery mode it booted in low resolution mode.

I tried everything for nvidia drivers i.e. purged, reinstalled through PPA etc. Also set `nomodeset`. After that it started booting on its own in low resolution mode.

Then while trying to reconfigure nvidia drivers I selected `lightdm` in place of gdm3 by mistake. Now it is stuck in a login loop. I tried to enter tty 1/2/3 and could enter tty 3. Tried to repair `lightdm`, installed `lxdm` and `lubuntu-desktop` even. But every desktop environment is stuck in loop. It allows me to login with my password but comes back to the login page again.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Question is confusing, but it looks to me like you have good plan. I agree you should make partitions. However, appears to me that the grub installer did not get it right. An expert might be able to correct this, for a beginner almost impossible you can repair your grub. If I were you, I would re run Ubuntu install from scratch. Let it rewrite everything.  When you get to last part about configuring boot loader, you can have it set up windows as an OS. As you note, the grub loader needs to be in a bootable drive.

I wouldn't bother with linux rescue approach until the system boots correctly once.  You need start over and create something worth rescuing.  I might mark the windows partition unbootable while testing this. But installing grub boot loader correctly will probably solve problem.

Your comments about "fixes" during boot raise concern. If you do Linux install, then change bios drive order, you will be in trouble because the Linux system does not find the drives in the places it expects. I would avoid doing tricks like that until you have more experience.

I had a lot of trouble on Dell laptops with Ubuntu 16.04. I am not convinced you benefit from it.

About poor display in rescue mode: that is supposed to be. Rescue mode is a command line to fix settings, not a working desktop.

The Nvidia card you have will not be supported by base drivers, you will need to Google on that problem.

Does your Ubuntu media offer a "live session"? You should try that, see if you like Gnome. Also, it is going to help see if your video works at all with free drivers. On my Dell systems, 16.04 caused a lot of 'black screens' that would not wake up. Problems have almost all disappeared in 17.04

Also possible the SSID drive support is better in newer OS.

Comment: Appreciate your answer. And yes it seems cofusing though, wanted to give as much details possible. Will try to install 17.04 from scratch. That was in my mind too. Wanted to give a try to this https://www.google.co.in/amp/s/jeremymdyson.wordpress.com/2016/04/27/ubuntugnome-16-04-on-asus-rog-gl552v/amp/ any idea whether this will work or reinstallation is the only option left?